# Using DCount in a For Loop with VBA (Microsoft Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, dcount

I'm having a problem with DCount in VBA.

I'm trying to fill an array with values calculated by Dcount. One of the criteria I use in the Dcount I want to get from a different array, this gives the problem:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To (intNumberOfSplitterboxes - 1)
    Dim arrFreeSingleModePorts(243) As Variant
    arrFreeSingleModePorts(i) = 
        DCount("ID", "SplitterboxPorts", _
        "SplitterboxID=i AND Mode='SingleMode' AND IsNull(DevicePortID) AND IsNull(SplitterboxPortID)")
Next
```

I get error 2471

Comment: declare your array variable outside the loop. DCount has incorrect string see below answer

Comment: Can you run this query successfully? SELECT Count(ID) FROM SplitterboxPorts WHERE SplitterboxID=1 AND Mode='SingleMode' AND IsNull(DevicePortID) AND IsNull(SplitterboxPortID)

Answer (score 0):

You have included your `i` variable inside of your string.  To use the actual value of `i` in your string you need to concatenate them together like this: `"SplitterboxID=" & i & " AND Mode='SingleMode' AND IsNull(DevicePortID) AND IsNull(SplitterboxPortID)"`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution. I understand what the problem is. But now I get a different error: Error 13, types don't match.

Comment: Does this error occur on the line `arrFreeSingleModePorts(i) = 
        DCount("ID", "SplitterboxPorts", _
        "SplitterboxID=i AND Mode='SingleMode' AND IsNull(DevicePortID) AND IsNull(SplitterboxPortID)")`